# What is the best way to train images that have text written on it?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pre-trained-model

I am having a problem in which I have images on which some text is written. 
Both image and text is important.
What I tried :
I took features from VGG16 model 
I extracted text using OCR then using bert took features of the text part.
Combined these features and made a big feature matrix.
I trained them using different ml/deep learning techniques but was not able to achieve accuracy. My accuracy was not more than 45%.
I need suggestions what can I do to make accuracy better. I need more alternative approaches.
Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to predict? how many output classes are there, since it can vary the approach!!

Comment: There are 5 classes  am trying to predict whether the image is very positive , positive , neutral , negative , very negative. The image consist some faces and text written on that image. Both are usefull information for me.